# Does QT support svg?

Tags: qt, svg

I'm testing the SVG Viewer, located in QT Examples and Example, and all SVG I tried doesnt show properly.

Is SVG fully suported in QT, or does it need extra work?

In SVG Viewer most of the elements are not shown.

I also tried QSvgWidget and results are even worse than thoose from SVG Viewer.

Comment: Did you test those files in your browser? Svg is supported and should work fine, if used correctly. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsvg-index.html

Comment: Yup i test it in browsers. They are fine. The files are rendering in my qt app, but they are messed up. Its looks like qt dont support new svg standards, only the basics.

Comment: Qt's SVG generally works fine, but I've definitely seen bugs where it renders differently in Inkscape, Firefox, etc.

Comment: Ok. i found what i was looking for. My SVG uses elements wich are outside of the spec for SVG Tiny 1.2. And Qt svg does not support it.

Comment: Exactly: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/svgrendering.html

Answer (score 0):

Qt aslo suport svg   in

```
  Image {source:'someinage.svg'}
```

you need to do what is said in link what felix posted in coments

i got it reasonably working with inkscape(exporing it to "plain svg" incspace) especialy when i tweeked manualy parameter

```
viewBox
```

to

```
viewbox="0 0 <width> <height>" 
// <width> and <height> was multiple of widhth and height of image in qml
// you must obyde ration of <width> and <height>
//i recomend higher  resolution qt can not scale svg properly up
```

still it had problems with gradients